# No recurring payment support in PayPal REST SDKs

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I use PayPal for once off and recurring payments.
The once off payments were relatively easy to implement using the [PayPalCheckoutSdk](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NET-SDK).

However, when it comes to making recurring payments, PayPal's [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/catalog-products/v1/) all refer to v1, whereas for the Orders (one off payments) API, it's v2.

Searching nuget, google and PayPal's own git repository doesn't seem to have much in the way of finding an sdk for recurring payments and their API examples are only in Bash for some strange reason.

Does anyone know if PayPal is planning to release an Orders sdk? Or if it's safe to use the old deprecated version?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if PayPal is planning to release an Orders sdk? Or if it's safe to use the old deprecated version?

There is an Orders v2 Checkout SDK, which is not for recurring payments.

There is no SDK for the current version of [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/). Use a [direct integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-credentials) (HTTPS API calls when needed, no SDK). Examples are given using the command-line tool `curl` since it is the most universal way to explain the text of an API request and response, but you will implement that HTTPS request from whatever environment you are using.

Do not use deprecated SDKs and APIs, such as that of v1/payments or the old Subscription endpoints (billing agreements).

The version in the URL is not a matter of deprecation per se, but indicates whether the schema has changed significantly (major revision). For one-time payments, v1/payments is deprecated in favor of v2/checkout/orders.  But other API operation (like those used for the current Subscriptions integration) still use v1 URLs.